# Can i convert my HEX private key to RAW form?

Tags: private-key

Sorry guys if this is a basic question but i am new to this. I have got my private key only in HEX format. converting to raw and then importing or directly making a wallet using HEX private key. Is it possible?

Comment: This question is not clear without you explaining what you mean by `converting to raw and then importing or directly making a wallet using HEX private key`. First of all, what do you mean by "raw" and what do you mean by "importing"? Second, the structure of this sentence in the context of your question is completely senseless. What does it mean "converting to raw and then importing **OR** directly making a wallet using HEX private key"? How is that even a question???

Comment: I have my private key in this format "0aa13882826d614232dc8b0583fc32b7dd9827fb7898a4156454c7284585d4ce"(This is not my key). I want to recover my funds from my key as i lost access to my wallet. I want to know how i can recover my funds using my private key in this format

Comment: HEX *is* the raw form for Ethereum private keys. What format are you looking to get it to?